# Resource that teaches everything about fractions

Tags: algebra-precalculus, reference-request, fractions

Is their a website that teaches you everything you need to know about fractions, just fractions.

I ask this because I do calculus...and I suck at fractions. I hate them so much. I have no idea how to manipulate them in equations or do anything. Especially compound fractions. I've never been taught fractions outside of rote learning equations.

please help!

Comment: The [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fraction_%28mathematics%29) may be more helpful than you might suspect.

Comment: once you have $\frac{a}{b}+\frac{c}{b}=\frac{a+c}{b}$ and $\frac{a}{b} \times \frac{c}{d} = \frac{ac}{bd}$, you basically have everything

Comment: maybe $1/\frac{a}{b}=\frac{b}{a}$ is good to be confident with?

Comment: oh and $\frac{ac}{bc}=\frac{a}{b}$ of course. This ought to be an answer

Comment: [This book](http://www.4shared.com/office/KTH-W3tYce/Fabulous_Fractions.html) and the [wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fraction_%28mathematics%29) explain everything you need.

Comment: A ressource by Rice University , Openstax , PreAlgebra , chapter 4 : https://openstax.org/details/books/prealgebra-2e

Comment: I rather suspect, since the OP is doing calculus, they are struggling with algebraic fractions and manipulating them, rather than with lower school fraction work in rational numbers

Answer (score 1):

All you need to know about fractions:

**Trivia**
$$\frac0A=0$$
$$\frac AA=1$$
$$\frac A0\text{ is forbidden}$$

**Sum and difference**$$\frac AB\pm\frac CD=\frac{AD\pm BC}{BD}$$
**Product**$$\frac AB\cdot\frac CD=\frac{AC}{BD}$$
**Quotient**$${\frac AB}:{\frac CD}={\frac AB}\div{\frac CD}={\frac AB}/{\frac CD}=\frac{\frac AB}{\frac CD}=\frac{AD}{BC}$$
**Power**$$\left(\frac AB\right)^\alpha=\frac{A^\alpha}{B^\alpha}$$
Fractions can be simplified when you see a common factor:

**Simplification**
$$\frac{AB}{CB}=\frac AC\frac BB=\frac AC$$
but this is something you already knew from the second relation.

And about compound fractions:

**Composition**
$$A\frac BC=\frac A1+\frac BC=\frac{AC+B}C$$
but this is something you  already knew from the first relation.

**Decomposition**
$$\frac AB=Q\frac RB,$$
where $Q$ is the quotient of the integer division of $A$ by $B$, and $R$ is the remainder.

Comment: It should also be noted that the mixed fraction notation $A\frac{B}{C} = \frac{A}{1} + \frac{B}{C}$ is ambiguous with the multiplication $A\frac{B}{C} = \frac{A}{1} \times \frac{B}{C} = \frac{AB}{C}$. Mixed fractions are rarely used and should be discouraged.

Comment: In actual usage, the notation $A\frac BC$ means a mixed fraction _exactly when_ $A$, $B$ and $C$ are all _bare numbers_. If _any_ of them is a variable or an arithmetic expression, then it means a product. So when one evaluates, for example, $2\frac{2+2}5$ step by step, one needs to careful to write the next step as $2\cdot\frac{4}{5}$ rather than $2\frac45$ to avoid suddenly writing something that will be read as a mixed fraction.

Comment: Also for trivialities don't forget to assume that $A\neq0$ in your two first properties.

Answer (score 1):

Too long for a comment…

It is well worth forgetting the “sum of fractions” formula because it is not a fact about fractions - simply a *consequence* of the other facts. To experts in fractions this sounds unnecessary, but this extra formula that needs remembering, with its seemingly magic multiplications, is a great stumbling block to the uninitiated.

Rather than saying $$\frac a b + \frac c d = \frac {ad+cb}{bd}$$

say simply $$\frac a e+ \frac c e = \frac {a+c}e$$

- that is, give the **obvious** answer to the “same denominator” case and give *no answer at all* to the question “what is the sum of two fractions with different denominators?”

Given that we also know that $\frac a b=\frac {ax}{bx}$, you can work out
$\frac a b + \frac c d$ for yourself by multiplying top and bottom of the first fraction by something and top and bottom of the second fraction by something, in such a way that the bottoms of both fractions are the same.

Of course this is exactly equivalent to the magic formula with $bd$ in the denominator, but it is a lot less confusing to say “I can do this” rather than “this memorised magic works but I don’t know why”.